# Can I make Prolog's "format/x" family behave leniently?

Tags: printing, prolog, formatting

We try this in SWI Prolog (to be precise: `SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.19-37-gc4fb81227)`)

```
?- format("Hello, ~w\n",[world]).
Hello, world
true.
```

Works, but now, we add an in-string placeholder (introduced by `~`) and forget to add the corresponding argument:

```
?- format("Hello, ~w. Goodbye ~w!\n",[world]).
Hello, world. Goodbye 
ERROR: Format error: not enough arguments
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] format("Hello, ~w. Goodbye ~w!\n",[world])
ERROR:    [9] <user>
?-
```

Or, using [`catch/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=catch/3):

```
?- catch(format("Hello, ~w. Goodbye ~w!\n",[world]),
        Xc,
        format("\n\nOh noes! Got Exception!", [Xc])).
Hello, world. Goodbye 

Oh noes! Got Exception!
Xc = error(format('not enough arguments'), context(system:format/2, _6584)).
```

Now, worrying about crashing on incorrect number of arguments when formatting output in an any-typed, dynamic language seems excessive.

Especially as `format/2` is ok with a non-list argument, i.e. already behaves leniently in the case of "one argument which is not a list":

```
?- format("Just one ~w argument", "beautiful").
Just one beautiful argument
true.
```

Same as:

```
?- format("Just one ~w argument", ["beautiful"]).
Just one beautiful argument
true
```

I would be more appropriate to issue "warning" at runtime and continue, leaving the developer to fix the program later. In a production system, a problem with `format/x` arguments might not be hit for some time and making it tear down the system is probably not what is wanted.

In other words, I would like to have the `format/x` family behave "leniently".

Is there a way to do so, other than writing my own `format/x` around the existing one? Like a flag? Other solutions involve over-the-top defensive coding:

- parse the format string in a wrapping `my_format/x` around `format/x` and either widen the argument list or zero out the placeholders;
- catch the exception in a wrapping `my_format/x` and suppress or re-attempt output with a changes argument list.

## Update: SWI-Prolog's `format/2` will actually become stricter

Going the other way, in the discussion [Too many arguments to format/2](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/too-many-arguments-to-format-2/1715), the design decision was taken to have `format/2` raise an Exception if there are too many arguments so that the only acceptable call is "exactly the right number of arguments".

Patch: [MODIFIED: format/1-3: raise an exception if there are more argument than](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/commit/68db1d6ab9602be575664fca86cfbd1fae753493)

---

---

## Addendum: Checking other systems/APIs

Below follows a lengthy and incomplete digression.

I started with just verifying `writef/x`, but then, tested a few other systems' behaviour just for fun & also practice.

Those "systems" fall into three general classes:

1. **Simple "format & print" APIs**, descended from C-library's [`printf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string), with format strings allowing various placeholder sequences. Prolog's `format/x` (from Quintus Prolog, widely used, but nonstandardized) and `writef/x` (from Edinburgh C Prolog, deprectated) predicates belong to this. Note that the character introducing a placeholder has been traditionally `%`. This is the case for `writef/x`, but for `format/x` it is `~`.

   - Some (dynamic) programming languages have simpler ["string interpolation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) features, where in-string placeholders are replaced with a string derived from a value of variables available in the current context: `"this is a ${adjective} test"` or even `"this is the ${counter.toString(longformat)}th test"`. No such thing exists in Prolog.
2. **Logging APIs and libraries**. These are generally highly configurable and even "pluggable" at process start. In the Java world, the package [`java.util.logging`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) has been the default since Java 1.4 (2002). However, there are others with different features and behaviour, like Ceki Gülcü's "[SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) + [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)" or [Apache Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) (which actually precedes `java.util.logging` by quite a bit).

   - In SWI Prolog, there is the [`print_message/2` predicate](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=printmsg). This should be used in preference to unrestrained `format/x` calls but it's still, IMHO, rather basic. In particular, only "debug level" messages can be assigned a "topic" and filtered based on this topic. Whether informational messages are printed out is controlled by the Prolog `verbose` flag (not by tuning a loglevel).
   - There is also [library(debug)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debug) which is meant to be used to emit debug messages, and which calls `print_message/2`. Messages are assigned to a "topic". By dynamically enabling or disabling topics the user can select desired messages. Debug statements are removed when the code is compiled for optimization.
3. **Templating libraries** that go beyond trying to generate program output via `format/x` calls. In the Java world, there is for example Terence Parr's [StringTemplate](https://www.stringtemplate.org/) or [Apache's Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/).

   - What is the equivalent in Prolog? Prolog is not likely to be the language to perform this operation, but if I absolutely wanted to generated HTML pages using Prolog?

And, a bit tangentially, so-called ["here documents"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). Prolog has these (more or less), as a string literal can be multiline. But there is no way to perform variable substitutions on such a string or even specify proper indentation, so it's a bit weak.

```
?- [user].
|: p(X) :- X = "This is some string
followed by several lines
   indented".
|: % user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- p(X).
X = "This is some string\nfollowed by several lines\n   indented".
```

So here is a non-representative assay...

### Simple "format & print" APIs

#### Re-implemented Edinburgh C-Prolog's `writef/x`

At least the implementation in SWI-Prolog of the (deprecated) ["writef family"](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=writef/2) behaves leniently (not sure about the original `writef/x`):

```
?- writef("1: %t 2: %t",[a,b]).
1: a 2: b
true.

?- writef("1: %t 2: %t",[a]).
1: a 2: %t
true.
```

#### Java's `java.util.Formatter`

[java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) is picky:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {

   public static void main(String[] argv) {
      Formatter f = new Formatter();
      System.out.println(f.format("%s %s %s %s", "a", "b", "c" ));
   }

}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2519)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
        at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Looks like checking a formatter specification, although out-of-language but evidently doable in most cases during (or rather, just after) parsing (i.e. "linting the `printf` string), is not a thing in 2020.

### Perl

Good old Larry knows how to party: Perl 5 (and probably Perl 6) just warns on argument count mismatch, and even just warns on argument type mismatch:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

printf "%d %s %s %s %s\n", "x", "a", "b", "c";
printf "Ok, Buddy!\n";
```

```
Argument "x" isn't numeric in printf at test.pl line 3.
Missing argument in printf at test.pl line 3.
0 a b c 
Ok, Buddy!
```

### C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(char *argv[],int argc) {
   printf("Hello, World! Goodbye, %s");
}
```

```
Hello, World! Goodbye, �^|��
```

We find a lack of out-of-bounds checking, at least in this compilate. Should even nominally "low-level" (...[but not really](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=3212479)) really allow this in 2020?

### Logging APIs and libraries

#### Java logging using "SLF4J over Logback"

- [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) is the "Simple Logging Façade for Java" - a thin API that can be implemented by one of "loging implementations", which is done by loading the required library at program initialization. By default, it logs nothing.
- [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/index.html) is a logging implementation, implementing the SLF4J API. Just make its jarfile available at runtime.

In a file called `MainSlf4j.java`:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MainSlf4j {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainSlf4j.class);
    String[] args1 = {"sweet", "you"};
    String[] args2 = {"forgetful"};
    logger.info("Hello, World. This is {} of {}", (Object[])args1);
    logger.info("Goodbye, World. This is {} of {}", (Object[])args2);
  }

}
```

Compile & run in bash:

```
cd jars
wget "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar"
wget "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar"
wget "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar"

cd code
export CLASSPATH=
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:jars/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:jars/logback-core-1.2.3.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:jars/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar 

javac MainSlf4j.java && java MainSlf4j
```

```
09:28:24.355 [main] INFO MainSlf4j - Hello, World. This is sweet of you
09:28:24.360 [main] INFO MainSlf4j - Goodbye, World. This is forgetful of {}
```

Yup, it's lenient. This of course can be changed - you keep the same SLF4J API but replace the implementation, Logback, by something stricter at process start time (this is done by replacing the Logback jar file by your own).

#### Java's `java.util.logging`

The out-of-the-box [java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html) logging facilities actually have no formatting capabilities and demand that you construct the messgae string by some other means.

So - not applicable.

### Templating libraries

#### Java templating using Terence Parr's "StringTemplate"

[StringTemplate main site](https://www.stringtemplate.org/) and [Introduction to StringTemplate](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/introduction.md).

Templates the tool to use to go once one attempts anything that can still be solved by spirited hacking using `printf` and its descendants.

This code is laborious because of laborious Java syntax. One should probably do it in Groovy.

In a file called `MainST.java`:

```
import org.stringtemplate.v4.*;

class MyData {

   public final String name;
   public final int id;

   MyData(String name, int id) {
      this.name = name; this.id = id;
   }
}


class MainST {

   public static void main(String[] argv) {
      {
         ST st = new ST("Hello, $x.name$; your number is $x.id$", '$', '$');
         st.add("x", new MyData("World", 1729));
         System.out.println("Good: " + st.render());
      }
      {
         System.out.println("Missing member 'name'...");
         ST st = new ST("Hello, $x.name$; your number is $x.otherid$", '$', '$');
         st.add("x", new MyData("World", 1729));
         System.out.println(st.render());
      }
       {
         System.out.println("Missing attribute 'x'...");
         ST st = new ST("Hello, $x.name$; your number is $x.id$", '$', '$');
         System.out.println(st.render());
      }
   }
}
```

Compile & run in bash:

```
cd jars
wget "https://www.stringtemplate.org/download/ST-4.3.jar"
wget "https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.8-complete.jar"

cd code
export CLASSPATH=
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:jars/antlr-4.8-complete.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:jars/ST-4.3.jar

javac MainST.java && java MainST
```

```
Good: Hello, World; your number is 1729
Missing member 'name'...
Hello, World; your number is 
Missing attribute 'x'...
context [anonymous] 1:8 attribute x isn't defined
context [anonymous] 1:33 attribute x isn't defined
Hello, ; your number is
```

Lenient, too. Not sure whether this is configurable.

Comment: For C you can consider yourself lucky that no daemons are swirling around.

Comment: @false That's the job of the CPU's Memory Management Unit to keep the processes in line. Believe it or not, I'm old enough to have seen Guru Meditations glitter in the dark near 20 MB harddisks.

Comment: My reference was to C, as it is defined. Not C as it runs on a concrete machine. How large was this hard disk?

Comment: 20 Megabyte (Seagate ST-225 5.25''). Slow as a dog, too.

Comment: Can you please include in the question the specific version of SWI-Prolog used. The reason I ask is that were you aware of this post in the SWI-Prolog forum: [Too many arguments to format/2](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/too-many-arguments-to-format-2/1715).

Comment: Why don't you post your problem to the SWI-Prolog forum. I suspect that Jan W. might agree and push a change. I know you are already a member of the forum.

Comment: @GuyCoder Thanks guy. Let me read the discussion on the forum ... (This is SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.19-37-gc4fb81227)) btw.

Comment: I checked with the latest *dev* version and what you note still happens. So while you may get an answer here, that will not get a fix pushed into the code.

Comment: Your Prolog catch example has ~!. But I guess you want ~w!. Thats why it shows a strange error message.

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse Ay! Good catch, thanks.

Comment: Changes to SWI-Prolog with regards to this post were in the check phase of building. See this [post](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/too-many-arguments-to-format-2/1715/14) on the SWI-Prolog Discourse forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lenient_format(S,A,L) :-
    catch(format(S,A,L),
          error(format('not enough arguments'),_),
           (append(L,[''],R), lenient_format(S,A,R))).

lenient_format(A,L) :-
    lenient_format(atom(H),A,L),
    write(H).
```

Works like a charm:

```
?- lenient_format("Hello, ~w. Goodbye ~w!\n",[world]).
Hello, world. Goodbye !
true.
```

But probably not very efficient.

Comment: I will accept this as answer, as I'm doing much the same in Java to not have unexpected process teardowns (I should probably increase test coverage, but I haven't reached that level yet). It should be inefficient if it happens on every call, but otherwise additional exception handling should not have a large impact (I think). Needs profiling though.

Answer (score 1):

I went through [SWI Environment Control (Prolog flags)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags). Good candidates are '[unknown](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags#flag:unknown)' and '[report_error](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags#flag:report_error)'. I was not able to get them to work. Try your luck. Otherwise, your only option is catch.

```
catch(format("Hello, ~w. Goodbye ~w!\n",[world]),Err, (true)).
```

with '[exception hooks](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=excepthook)' to 'fix' the error just-in-time.

Are you sure you are not able to avoid the issue in the first place?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes I get annoyed enough that I go down rabbit holes.

Comment: That exception hook is interesting, but it is really for decorating the exception term, not for making the exception disappear.